# Working with bindinglist

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview and a bindinglist. They work together pretty ok, but I want to make the properties appear in the rows, not on the column. Is there any way to achieve that ? 
My code for anyone who is interested.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim listaBindingSource As New BindingList(Of pessoa)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim b1 As New pessoa()
    listaBindingSource.Add(b1)
    dgv.DataSource = listaBindingSource
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class pessoa

Dim sells_Month1 As String

Public Sub New() 'ByVal nome_fora As String)

    sells_Month1 = "0"

End Sub

Property vendas1 As String
    Get
        Return sells_Month1
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sells_Month1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The other properties are vendas2, vendas3.. and are the same as this one.

Edit:
I´m kind of lost here. What I want is to make the values of the properties of my objects appear on some kind of data visualizer. When I add new objects on the list, they appear on this data visualizer and when I change the values of the cells there, the values of the properties change. Anyone has a good sugestion ? Apparentely dgv is not the way to go.

Thanks, 
Ricardo S.

Comment: You want to implement a [property grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx) control, as in Visual Studio designer (F4 shortcut), correct?

Comment: Kind of. The problem is that the property grid doesn´t make me multiple columns - what is really necessary.

Comment: Okay, so you want a [Vertical Grid Control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2461)?

Comment: Have you tried [SourceGrid](http://sourcegrid.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: I think SourceGrid is just for C#.

Comment: You can build as DLL and then use in your VB.NET project.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make the properties appear in the rows´ headers, not on
>   the column.

I'm afraid this is not possible, there is no built-in solution for that in `DataGidView`. You can display the properties in columns only.

To control the text displayed in the column header, try to set the `DisplayName` attribut:

```
<System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("DisplayedText")>
Property vendas1 As String
    Get
        Return sells_Month1
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sells_Month1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Or if you import `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

```
<DisplayName("DisplayedText")>
Property vendas1 As String
    Get
        Return sells_Month1
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        sells_Month1 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Do you know any other approach to do what I want ? Summarizing, I want to work on my object through some kind of data visualizer, but the properties should start filling from the rows.

Comment: @Ricardoytu I guess you are looking for something like a  `PropertyGrid` but with more than one column. Unfortunately, `PropertyGrid` doesn't support multiple objects, so it's not a solution. Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010086/flipping-columns-and-rows-in-datagridview/17010509#17010509)

Comment: Hmm... Do you I can do something with a datatable ? I have already done some, but I just can´t bind.

Comment: @Ricardoytu If you are trying to do what I suggest in the other answer, I think it won't be possible to bind the `datagridview`, you will need to populate the grid yourself. Using a `datatable` won't change anything. `Datagridview` is not designed to work like this.

Comment: I have choosen datagridview because I thought it would be a good control to display my object properties and work on it changing the values on its properties. Would you use another control or other approach ? I am really lost here. Binding is essential.

Comment: @Ricardoytu You can use binding with `DataGridView` to display your objects in *rows* only. As I said, the `PropertyGrid` doesn't support multi-columns. So unless you use a third-party control or you use `DataGridView` in *standard* way, I don't see.